# Last Date of specific day from current Date Formula

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

I have a requirement where i want to calculate last Date of a given day based on today's Date. For example I have a method

```
DateTime GetDate(DateTime now, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
  //Logic goes here
}
```

**For e.g**

1. If i pass friday in dayofWeek and today is Monday, then it should
   return me last friday date.
2. If i pass friday and today is friday then same date should be
       return.

**Conditions:**

1. I just want to use formula to calculate the date.
2. Don't want anything to be assumed or hard-coded.
3. I don't want to use if...else.

Comment: Why don't you want to use if/else? While I can see that it may not be necessary, it *may* end up being the cleanest approach. Do you want to keep the same time of day?

Comment: This sounds like a work instruction, what have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how my question looks a work instruction, i just want to know the shortest formula, it can be done using if, loops, but i was trying to develop a formula which i couldn't, so i have posted it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work out how many days to subtract by comparing the current day of week with the target one, wrapping round in case it's negative:

```
static DateTime GetDate(DateTime now, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    // Number of days to subtract, e.g. 1 for "today is Friday, we want Thursday"
    // The ((...) + 7) % 7 part is to handle wrap-around for negative values.
    int daysDifference = ((now.DayOfWeek - dayOfWeek) + 7) % 7;
    return now.AddDays(-daysDifference);
}
```

Or using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) (my date/time API which allow for a cleaner representation of "just a date" etc):

```
static LocalDate GetDate(LocalDate today, IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    return today.IsoDayOfWeek == dayOfWeek ? today : today.Previous(dayOfWeek);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

```
DateTime GetDate(DateTime now, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    var day = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
    var result = now;

    while(result.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
    {        
        result = result.Substract(day)
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static DateTime GetDate(DateTime todayDate, DayOfWeek dayofweek)
{
    while (todayDate.DayOfWeek != dayofweek)
    {
        todayDate = todayDate.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return todayDate;
}
```